# Macbook Pro late 2013 WiFi flaky

Tags: wifi, macintosh, broadcom

My WiFi is very flaky.

I installed broadcom-wl-dkms

```
broadcom-wl-dkms 6.30.223.271-20

[dewi@DEWILAPTOP modprobe.d]$ uname -a
Linux DEWILAPTOP 5.4.13-arch1-1-macbook #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 13 11:22:53 GMT 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

hwinfo

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0134]
        Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
```

Here in my dmesg:

```
[Sun Feb 16 21:58:03 2020] audit: type=1131 audit(1581890283.612:56): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[Sun Feb 16 21:58:25 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[Sun Feb 16 21:58:25 2020] audit: type=1130 audit(1581890305.878:57): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[Sun Feb 16 21:58:36 2020] audit: type=1131 audit(1581890316.605:58): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[Sun Feb 16 21:58:59 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station :
[Sun Feb 16 21:58:59 2020] Wrong Mac address, mac = 78:8a:20:58:1c:6a   profile =fc:ec:da:a7:4e:6c
[Sun Feb 16 21:58:59 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station :
[Sun Feb 16 21:58:59 2020] Wrong Mac address, mac = 78:8a:20:58:1c:6a   profile =fc:ec:da:a7:4e:6c
[Sun Feb 16 21:59:03 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station :
[Sun Feb 16 21:59:03 2020] Wrong Mac address, mac = 78:8a:20:58:1c:6a   profile =fc:ec:da:a7:4e:6c
[Sun Feb 16 21:59:03 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station :
[Sun Feb 16 21:59:03 2020] Wrong Mac address, mac = 78:8a:20:58:1c:6a   profile =fc:ec:da:a7:4e:6c
[Sun Feb 16 21:59:09 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station :
[Sun Feb 16 21:59:09 2020] Wrong Mac address, mac = 78:8a:20:58:1c:6a   profile =fc:ec:da:a7:4e:6c
[Sun Feb 16 21:59:09 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station :
[Sun Feb 16 21:59:09 2020] Wrong Mac address, mac = 78:8a:20:58:1c:6a   profile =fc:ec:da:a7:4e:6c
[Sun Feb 16 21:59:25 2020] audit: type=1130 audit(1581890365.618:59): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[Sun Feb 16 21:59:34 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[Sun Feb 16 21:59:35 2020] audit: type=1131 audit(1581890375.602:60): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[Sun Feb 16 22:00:43 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station :
[Sun Feb 16 22:00:43 2020] Wrong Mac address, mac = 78:8a:20:58:1c:6a   profile =78:8a:20:57:1c:6a
[Sun Feb 16 22:00:43 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station :
[Sun Feb 16 22:00:43 2020] Wrong Mac address, mac = 78:8a:20:58:1c:6a   profile =78:8a:20:57:1c:6a
[Sun Feb 16 22:00:59 2020] audit: type=1130 audit(1581890459.612:61): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[Sun Feb 16 22:01:03 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[Sun Feb 16 22:01:09 2020] audit: type=1131 audit(1581890469.602:62): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[Sun Feb 16 22:01:38 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station :
[Sun Feb 16 22:01:38 2020] Wrong Mac address, mac = 78:8a:20:58:1c:6a   profile =fc:ec:da:a7:4e:6c



[Sun Feb 16 22:02:02 2020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[Sun Feb 16 22:02:04 2020] audit: type=1131 audit(1581890524.602:64): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[Sun Feb 16 22:02:36 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station :
[Sun Feb 16 22:02:36 2020] Wrong Mac address, mac = 78:8a:20:58:1c:6a   profile =fc:ec:da:a7:4e:6c
[Sun Feb 16 22:02:36 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station :
[Sun Feb 16 22:02:36 2020] Wrong Mac address, mac = 78:8a:20:58:1c:6a   profile =fc:ec:da:a7:4e:6c
[Sun Feb 16 22:02:40 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station :
[Sun Feb 16 22:02:40 2020] Wrong Mac address, mac = 78:8a:20:58:1c:6a   profile =fc:ec:da:a7:4e:6c
[Sun Feb 16 22:02:40 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station :
[Sun Feb 16 22:02:40 2020] Wrong Mac address, mac = 78:8a:20:58:1c:6a   profile =fc:ec:da:a7:4e:6c
[Sun Feb 16 22:02:46 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station :
[Sun Feb 16 22:02:46 2020] Wrong Mac address, mac = 78:8a:20:58:1c:6a   profile =fc:ec:da:a7:4e:6c
[Sun Feb 16 22:02:46 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station :
[Sun Feb 16 22:02:46 2020] Wrong Mac address, mac = 78:8a:20:58:1c:6a   profile =fc:ec:da:a7:4e:6c
[Sun Feb 16 22:03:02 2020] audit: type=1130 audit(1581890582.615:65): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=NetworkManager-dispatcher comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[Sun Feb 16 22:03:02 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan :
[Sun Feb 16 22:03:02 2020] WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[Sun Feb 16 22:03:07 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan :
[Sun Feb 16 22:03:07 2020] WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[Sun Feb 16 22:03:08 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan :
[Sun Feb 16 22:03:08 2020] WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[Sun Feb 16 22:03:09 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan :
[Sun Feb 16 22:03:09 2020] WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[Sun Feb 16 22:03:10 2020] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan :
[Sun Feb 16 22:03:10 2020] WLC_SCAN error (-22)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using NetworkManager
Remove NetworkManager and use wpa_supplicant directly. It works much much better :) :) :)

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wpa_supplicant

Not sure what mischief NetworkManager was doing :/

hmmmmmm